# Как поменять иконку луны на иконку солнца, при нажатии на кнопку смены темы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<button onclick="test()" class="theme-button bx bx-moon" id="theme-button"></button>
```

---

```
var btn = document.getElementById("theme-button");
var link = document.getElementById("theme-link");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () { ChangeTheme(); });

function ChangeTheme()
{
    let lightTheme = "styles/light.css";
    let darkTheme = "styles/dark.css";

    var currTheme = link.getAttribute("href");
    var theme = "";

    if(currTheme == lightTheme)
    {
     currTheme = darkTheme;
     theme = "dark";
    }
    else
    {    
     currTheme = lightTheme;
     theme = "light";
    }

    link.setAttribute("href", currTheme);

}

function test() {
    if(btn.classList = 'bx-moon'){
    btn.classList.remove('bx-moon')
    btn.classList.add('bx-sun')
    btn.classList.add('bx')
    }}
```

Comment: В `if` вы присваиваете (`=`), а не сравниваете (`==` или `===`). Так же, `classList` является объектом, как следствие нужно обратиться к непосредственно строке с классами `btn.classList.value`, но в нём лежит всё (`theme-button bx bx-moon`), т.е. нужно использовать в условии что-то вроде `btn.classList.value.indexOf('bx-moon') != -1` дабы проверить наличие конкретного класса.

Comment: У меня всё равно почему-то не получается, не могли бы вы пожалуйста написать код полностью?

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `if` вы [присваиваете](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#prisvaivanie) (`=`), а не [сравниваете](https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison) (`==` или `===`). В `ChangeTheme`, например идёт сравнение (`currTheme == lightTheme`).

Так же, `classList` является объектом, который содержит все классы, т.е. нужно использовать в условии что-то вроде `btn.classList.contains('bx-moon')` дабы проверить наличие конкретного класса.

- [Element.classList | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("theme-button");

function test() {
  if(btn.classList.contains('bx-moon')) {
    btn.classList.remove('bx-moon')
    btn.classList.add('bx-sun')
  }
}
```

```css
.bx {
  padding: 10px;
}

.bx-moon {
  background: blue;
}

.bx-sun {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()" class="theme-button bx bx-moon" id="theme-button"></button>
```

Comment: У `classList` есть метод `contains`, а если уж так хочется через `indexOf` тогда уж лучше `className` использовать для упрощённой записи.

Comment: @ΝNL993, разумно, спасибо. Добавил в ответ.